# Switch element class after a click from a previous page

Tags: javascript, class, onload

I'm stuck since a long time so I'd like some help to solve my problem.

I have 2 pages. From the first `page A`, I have `<a href>` that link to an other page. Here is the link :

```
<div class="sucre" id="sucreFirst"><a href="ecole2.html"><img src="_img/slide06.jpg" width="634" height="308" alt=""/></a></div>
```

On the other `page B`, I have a menu that hide and show content withe `CSS` class.
Here is the code for the menu :

```
 <div id="menu_G">
    <p><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('Titre1').className='ON';document.getElementById('Titre2').className='OFF';document.getElementById('Titre3').className='OFF'">Le mariage de 2 expériences</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('Titre1').className='OFF';document.getElementById('Titre2').className='ON';document.getElementById('Titre3').className='OFF'">Né d'une conviction</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('Titre1').className='OFF';document.getElementById('Titre2').className='OFF';document.getElementById('Titre3').className='ON'">Des DRH militants</a></p>
  </div>
```

As you can see, the `page B` is set to show the `titre1` first.

```
<div class="ON" id="Titre1">content</div>
<div class="OFF" id="Titre2">content</div>
<div class="OFF" id="Titre3">content</div>
```

When I clic on the link from the `page A` i'll like it change property of the `titre3` class to `ON`.

To resume, when I clic on the link from `page A` I'd like it show the `titre3` content of `page B`.

I've tried many things but it always link to `titre1`.

Thanks for reading,

Alfred

Comment: In the code I post I forget to set the anchor on #Titre3.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Maybe you can show me a fiddle?

Comment: I'd recommend refactoring those document.getElem... script calls into a .js file, and just calling "onClick" for all the buttons. You can get the id of the currentTarget and do your class manipulation there, which will probably give you a cleaner idea of what's going on. Whether or not it matters in your context, the code as written would be considered "spaghetti".

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Probably yes. It's not the point right now but I think after applying the great tips from Alon_A, I will rebuild this part..... and a lot from this website throught century.

Comment: Thanks @user2507. You make me think I have to find time to work on fiddle. Sign up for soon sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have multiple ways to acheive your goal, so I'll give you an idea and a start point.
What you actually need to do is transferring information from the source page to the target page, the information transferred will be the element to turn ON and the elements to turn OFF.

One of the simple ways to send data between pages is by a URL Query String. You can create the Query String by simply adding it to the link.

Modify your link to:

```
href="ecole2.html?on=1&firstOFF=2&secondOFF=3"
```

The part from the `?` is the query string, its structure  is:

`?key=value&key=value&key=value...&key=value`

Now, when entering `ecole2.html` with this link, you'll be able to get those 3 variables (`on`, `firstOFF` and `secondOFF`) by a query string parser ([you have many ways to do it](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parse%20query%20string%20javascript)).

Create a function which will get the parameters and will set the visibility upon them, something like:

```
function setVisibility(onElement, firstOffElement, secondOffElement)
{
    document.getElementById(onElement).className='ON';
    document.getElementById(firstOffElement).className='ON';
    document.getElementById(secondOffElement).className='ON';
}
```

Call this function with each parameter when the page loads (`onload` event) and you're done.

```
<body onload="setVisibility(on, firstOff, secondOff)">
```

when `on` for example will be the string `"Titre"+onParsedVariableFromQueryString`

[Here is a jsdiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alon_A/6fasrf7a/2/) with a parsing URL function and actual parsing of three variables defined in the same way explained above. As the question is not directly about URL parsing, I see no need posting the actual parsing method code here.

With the above logic and examples I'm sure you can progress by your own.

Comment: Thanks @Alon_A, that sound really good. I'll try this tomorrow morning. I've read carefully and will probably have questions about **parsing URL** to go further. As you said I should progress on it.

Comment: Hello, I've tested your solution. But maybe I've missed something because that don't change the **Titre3 class to ON**. I've modified the href like this : `<a href="ecole2.html?Titre3=1&Titre2=2&Titre1=3">`. I set the Titre3Elemen to ON : `function setVisibility(onElement, firstOffElement, secondOffElement)
{
  document.getElementById(Titre3Element).className='ON';
    document.getElementById(Titre2Element).className='OFF';
    document.getElementById(Titre1Element).className='OFF';
}`. And finally add **pageB** : `<body onload="setVisibility(Titre3, Titre2, Titre1)">`. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: I've modified my code. It's better meaning I think but still not work. I've modified the href like this : `<a href="ecole2.html?ON=Titre3&OFF=Titre2&OFF=Titre1">`. I set the Titre3 to ON : `function setVisibility(Titre3, Titre2, Titre1)
{
  document.getElementById(Titre3).className='ON';
    document.getElementById(Titre2).className='OFF';
    document.getElementById(Titre1).className='OFF';
}`. And finally add **pageB** : `<body onload="setVisibility(Titre3, Titre2, Titre1)">`. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @AlfredWallace I've prepared a [fully working example](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/QGmPJR?editors=1111) using my suggested logic and a parsing URL method I've found (No need to invent the wheel on the URL parsing part). I've used the following link: `"ecole2.html?Titre1=OFF&Titre2=OFF&Titre3=ON"`. You can either press the button to hide the div or un-comment the `onload` event to hide it on refresh. Use it, learn from it, and feel free to accept my answer and/or +1 it :)

Comment: Thanks @Alon_A ! That's nice from you. I'd like +1 but I don't find any button for. A clue ?

Comment: @AlfredWallace Ahh, you can only [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) when you'll have 15 reputation. If you feel like, you can accept my answer (and other answers in the future) by pressing the `V` icon in the top left side of the answer

Comment: AllRight @Alon_A ! I've pressed it. Thanks again.